# How do I split a String in CSH?

Tags: csh

For example, I want to split "one,two,three" with comma as delimiter and use a loop to process the resulted three substring separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example:

```
set s = "one,two,three"
set words = `echo $s:q | sed 's/,/ /g'`
foreach word ($words:q)
    echo $word:q
end
```

But consider whether csh is the right tool for whatever job you're doing:

http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/text/cshbad.txt

Comment: Thanks. What does :q mean here?

Comment: It quotes the variable; `$s:q` is similar to `"$s"`.  It's not needed for this example, but it might be in other cases (say, where you have whitespace in the data).

Answer (score 14):

A simpler solution than the current one presented involves using the built-in substitution modifer -- there is no need or reason to wastefully use a loop or external command substitution in this instance:

```
set list = one,two,three
set split = ($list:as/,/ /)

echo $split[2] # returns two
```

() creates a list, the :s is the substitution modifier and :as repeats the subtitution as many times as needed.

Furthermore, t/csh does not require quoting of bare strings, nor variables that do not require forced evaluation.

Comment: What if list = "one,two or three,four"?
How do you get: "two or three"?

Comment: Maybe then: echo "$list" | awk -F',' '{print $2}' is better...

Answer (score 3):

```
set list = one,two,three
foreach i ( $list:as/,/ / )
  echo $i
end
```

Comment: Can you explain wt is function